# How to deploy a hadoop solution?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to learn how to deploy a hadoop solution but couldn't find an effective resource that lists and explains step by step guide to deploy a hadoop solution. Can anyone point me to an effective resource for this? Also what are some important issues one should take care while deploying a hadoop solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can Use the Amazon EMR (Amazon Elastic MapReduce)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-application.html